# Edit Items in a List Using Modal in Ionic 3

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic3

I have created an Array and I'm adding items to the array using Modal.
Now i need to edit the item by selecting it from the list.
please help me with the Code.
How to fetch the item to modal and bring back the edited item in the same place in the list

HOME.HTML

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let grocery of itemsArray">{{grocery}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button round (click)="addItem()">Add Item</button>
</ion-content>
```

HOME.TS

```
    export class HomePage {

  public itemsArray = [];
  newItem: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.newItem = this.navParams.get('data');
    this.itemsArray = [

    ];

  }
  public addItem() {
    let modalPage = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
    modalPage.onDidDismiss(data => {
      this.itemsArray.push(data.name
);
    });
    modalPage.present();
  } 



}
```

MODAL.HTML

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Add Item</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button (click)="closeModal()">Close</button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Item</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newItem"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="add()">Add Item</button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

MODAL.TS

```
    export class ModalPage {
  name:any;
  newItem: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public viewCtrl: ViewController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }


  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ModalPage');
  }
  public closeModal() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();

  }
  //add() {
  //  let data = {"name": this.newItem};
  //  this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data.name)
 // }
 add() {
  let data = {"name": this.newItem};
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data)
}

}
```

The code untill now works fine.

Comment: So you would like to be able to edit an item just by clicking on it ? It would open a modal and you could edit the name of the item ?

Comment: Yes! Exactly..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using alert controller to simplify your code in your use case. If you would need a modal - you can elaborate the code later.

Try this approach:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let grocery of itemsArray; let i = index">
    <ion-item (click)="changeItemName(grocery, i)">{{grocery}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button round (click)="addItem()">Add Item</button>
</ion-content>
```

Place iterator on the list and capture "index" per item, so that you could pass that value if particular item from the list is clicked together with actual grocery item name.

In your home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public itemsArray = ["milk", "butter", "bread"];
  newItem: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  public changeItemName(currentName, index) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Change grocery item name:',
      message: 'current: "' + currentName + '"',
      inputs: [
        {
          placeholder: 'type in a new name'
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
        },
        {
          text: 'Confirm',
          handler: data => {
            if (data[0].length === 0) {
              this.itemsArray[index] = currentName;
            } else {
              this.itemsArray[index] = data[0];
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  };

  public addItem() {
    let index = this.itemsArray.length;
    this.changeItemName("New item", index);
  }

}
```

You can use alert controller to show a small pop-up with input field. In the code you will see that we pass parameters to it and we modify list item name OR we add item to the list if change name method was called by addItem method.

Let me know if this is helpful for you.

Here is a working snippet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-urbtag

Comment: @sargey Thank you! This works fine! 
I also have to figure out to do the same using Modals!
Thanks for helping me out with the basic structure! 
Cheers!